# How many tetrahedrons in a tetrahedron?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

Given a regular tetrahedron. All the edges were divided into N equal segments. How many non-degenerate ($|\text{volume}| > 0$) tetrahedrons with vertices at the points of division can be built inside this tetrahedron? Vertex of given tetrahedron can't be the point of division.

I'm looking for a formula.

Examples:
For $N=2$, answer is $12$.
For $N=37$, answer is $65561472$.

Comment: Can you provide values between 2 and 37?  I don't find 6556147 in OEIS.  Was it a brute force search to get these?  Does the last sentence in the first paragraph say you can't use the vertices of the original tetrahedron in the small one?  I think it would be more natural to allow that, and you might find something in OEIS

Comment: If you really disallow the vertices of the given tetrahedron, how can you produce more than one tetrahedron in the case $N=2$? There are only four division points in total ...

Comment: @hagenvoneitzen there are 6 edges and hence 6 division points. This give 15 tetrahedra but 3 of them are degenerate. The number I don't understand is 6554147. This is smaller than 12(N-1)^4, a trivial lower bound I can establish.

Comment: I don't see the 3 degenerate ones in the $N=2$ case.  Your six division points form a triangular antiprism with all sides $\frac 12$, but I can't find any four in one plane.

Comment: @rossmillikan a tetrahedron has 3 pairs of opposite edges. remove a pair of that, the midpoints of the remain 4 edges forms a square.

Comment: I wrote a little program for this and get 12,417,2481,8448 for N=2,3,4,5.  Does that match your numbers?  I haven't checked it too hard yet.

Comment: Doesn't match my numbers. I get $12,257,1401,4608$ for $N = 2\ldots5$ and $32902272$ for $37$.

Comment: @achillehui:  257 seems quite low for $N=3$  There are $12$ points to pick from and ${12 \choose 4}=495$ so you would have half of them being degenerate.

Comment: @rossmillikan I found the bug in my counting. I can reproduce your number for $N = 2 \ldots 5$ and $65561472$ for $N = 37$.

Comment: @achillehui could you please tell me how you found these values ​​in your program? What formula did you use?

Comment: I just calculated the coordinates, looped over sets of 4 points, and used the Wikipedia dot/cross product  formula for the volume and counted those large enough to be nonzero

Comment: @rossmillikan actually, we can do loop over two points. Position of other points is not difficult to calculate. But due to symmetry some of these tetrahedrons can be calculated more than once.

Comment: @achillehui:  it appears OP lost a figure off the end of 65561472.  I agree with that number, as well.

Answer (score 4):

This is the partial result I have.

Let $m = N-1$, the number of non-degenerate tetrahedron $\mathcal{N}_N$ is given by:

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{N}_N &= 3\binom{m}{2}^2 + 48\binom{m}{2}m^2 + 15m^4 - 3\mathcal{O}_N\\
&= \frac34 m^2 (53m^2 - 34 m + 1) -3\mathcal{O}_N
\end{align}$$
where $\mathcal{O}_N$ is something which I didn't have a close form expression.

$\mathcal{O}_N$ is the number of degenerate tetrahedra where the four vertices are taken from two pairs of opposite edges of original tetrahedron. The factor $3$ before $\mathcal{O}_N$ is there because there are 3 possible choices for the two pairs.
It can be shown that $\mathcal{O}_N$ is the number of solutions for the following equation:
$$\frac{u}{N-u}\frac{z}{N-z} = \frac{v}{N-v}\frac{w}{N-w}$$
where $u, v, w, z \in \{1,\ldots,m\}$. $\mathcal{O}_N$ is something of order $O(3N^2)$
and can be computed with following algorithm in $O(N^2 \log N)$ steps.

```
histogram = {};  
for( u = 1; u < N; u++){    
    U = u/(N-u);    
    for( z = 1; z < N; z++){
        Z = z/(N-z);
        histogram{U*Z}++;    
    } 
} 
number_degen = 0;
foreach fraction in histogram {
    number_degen += histogram{fraction}^2;
}
return number_degen;
```

For example, when $N = 37$, $\mathcal{O}_N = 4836$ and $\mathcal{N}_N = 65575980 - 3*4836 = 65561472$.

**EDIT**

Let me explain the logic behind the algorithm and why its complexity is $O(N^2 \log N)$.

Consider a simpler example where $f$ is a function which sends
$1, 2, 3, 4, 5$ to $0, 0, 1, 1, 1$ respectively.
To count the number of solutions for $f(x) = f(y)$,
you don't need to loop over $x$ and $y$ twice. Instead, you loop over $x$ once to find
$f(x) = 0$ twice and $f(x) = 1$ three times.

For $f(x) = f(y) = 0$, $(x, y)$ can be any one of the $2^2$ combinations:
$$(1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (2,2)$$ 
For $f(x) = f(y) = 1$, $(x, y)$ can be any one of the $3^2$ combinations:
$$(3,3), (3,4), (3,5), (4,3), (4,4), (4,5), (5,3), (5,4), (5,5)$$

So there are $13 = 2^2 + 3^2$ solution for this simpler problem. The key is once
the histogram of the range of $f$ is known. One can compute the total number of
solutions by summing the square of the counts.

If one apply this to count the solutions for
$$\frac{u}{N-u}\frac{z}{N-z} = \frac{v}{N-v}\frac{w}{N-w}$$
you can construct the histogram in $O(N^2)$ steps.

On the surface, the complexity of the algorithm is $O(N^2)$ instead of $O(N^2\log N)$.
But the truth is the possible values of fractions are not that uniform and not that direct to represent in computer. One need to use some higher-level data structure to hold the histogram for fast access and manipulation.

I use an associated hash in Perl to do the dirty work. In other language, you may need to implement the data structure yourself. In the worst case, you can always implement the histogram using a binary tree. During the lifetime of the loop, the histogram will be holding the counts of $O(N^2)$ fraction. So each access/modification of the binary tree itself contribute a $O(\log(N^2))$ factor. The final complexity is $\sum_{O(N^2)} O(\log N) \sim O( N^2 \log N)$.

**EDIT2**

For people requesting actual code, a Perl implementation is given below.

```
use Math::BigRat;
my $N   = 37;
my %histogram = ();
for( my $u = 1; $u < $N; $u++ ){
    my $fU = Math::BigRat->new(sprintf('%d/%d',$u,$N-$u));
    for( my $z = 1; $z < $N; $z++ ){
        my $fZ = Math::BigRat->new(sprintf('%d/%d',$z,$N-$z));
        $histogram{ ($fU*$fZ)->bstr() }++;
    }
}
my $number_degen = 0;
foreach my $count (values %histogram){
    $number_degen += $count*$count;
}
printf "number_degen = %d\n", $number_degen;
```

Comment: Good job! This result is much better than I got in two days.

Comment: Yesterday I copied your pseudocode to Python, and got that [http://pastebin.com/jftVNq04](http://pastebin.com/jftVNq04)

Comment: Perl is probably handling the doubles differently than Python. Using a *factor* for different $N$, sometimes I get the right number, sometimes I don't.

Comment: Assume you have a function to compute gcd, a safer version is to replace the innermost loop by something like:    
            numer = u*z;  
            denom = (N-u)*(N-z);  
            gcd   = gcd( numer, denom );  
            numer /= gcd;  
            denom /= gcd;  
            histogram{numer/denom}++;

Comment: I always get correct number (at least for $N<3000$). Can you give an example $N$, for which answer is incorrect? Probably you should increase factor if $N>3000$.

Comment: this GCD will give me additional $log(min(numer, denom))$, so result is $O(N^2 log(N)^2)$.

Comment: About the factor issue, it start to fail at very small N under Perl. About the GCD issue, the extra $O(\log N)$ factor add to the $O(\log N)$ factor of accessing the histogram, the overall complexity is still $O(N^2\log N)$. In my case, the use of GCD eliminate the need of the Math::BigRat package which has quite a bit of overhead to use. For $N = 1000$, it speed up my computation an order of magnitude and I can get a number $3260983$ in about 8 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{u}{N-u}\frac{z}{N-z} = \frac{v}{N-v}\frac{w}{N-z}$$ 
the number of solutions in this case $1296$ ($N=37$)...
I tested your formula in program and found some mistake.
This formula must looks 
$$\frac{u}{N-u}\frac{z}{N-z} = \frac{v}{N-v}\frac{w}{N-w}$$
in this case it gets $4836$ ($N=37$)

P.S.  My solusion was $O(N^4)$. How to write program for this in $O(N^2 \log N)$? Not in pseudo-code please.

Comment: There is a typo in my equation and I fixed that. Please see update of my answer for the logic behind the $O(N^2 \log N)$ complexity.

Comment: int number_degen = 0;

for (i = 0; i<histogram.size(); i++)
{

    number_degen += histogram[i]*histogram[i];

}

when i am trying to make something like this it gets 950404 (N=37).
Tell me please where i am wrong.

Comment: I don't know how to put code in comment, update the original answer once again.

Comment: looks like you have used integer to store the value of a fraction. i.e. your number 950404 corresponds to the number of solutions for $\lfloor\frac{u}{N-u}\rfloor\lfloor\frac{z}{N-z}\rfloor =\lfloor\frac{v}{N-v}\rfloor\lfloor\frac{w}{N-w}\rfloor$.

Answer (score 1):

A remark concerning degeneracy: The only difficult case is when the four vertices of the inner tetrahedron lie on four different edges of the large tetrahedron, no three of them concurrent.

To investigate this case assume that the vertices of the large tetrahedron are given by $$(N,0,-N), \quad (0,N,N),\quad (-N,0,-N),\quad (0,-N,N)$$
and the four vertices of the inner tetrahedron by
$$\eqalign{&(k_1,N-k_1,N-2k_1),\quad(-k_2, N-k_2,N-2k_2),\cr &(-k_3, k_3-N,N-2k_3),\quad(k_4, k_4-N, N-2k_4)\cr}$$
with $1\leq k_i\leq N-1$. The condition that these four points are not complanar amounts to a certain determinant being nonzero. This determinant is a polynomial of degree $3$ in the $k_i$ and $N$ which does not factor in an obvious way. As a consequence "arithmetic coincidences" will play a large rôle in the counting process.

Comment: The volume of the inner tetrahedron:
$$\left|\frac{k_2k_4N - k_1k_3N - k_2k_3k_4 + k_1k_3k_4 - k_1k_2k_4 + k_1k_2k_3}{27}\right|$$
can be factored as:
$$\frac{\prod_{i=1}^4(N - k_i)}{27N}\left|\frac{k_1k_3}{(N-k_1)(N-k_3)} - \frac{k_2k_4}{(N-k_2)(N-k_4)}\right|$$

Answer (score 0):

I find it more natural to add the corners of the original tetrahedron, but maybe that doesn't fit yo8ur problem.  I find then $$\begin {array} {r r} N&\text{tetrahedrons}\\
2&141\\3&1256\\4&5128\\5&14517\\6&33113\\7&65584\\8&117528\\9&195497 \end {array}$$
which is approximately quartic in $N$ and not in OEIS.

Comment: Maybe if you include degenerate tetrahedra, you'll get a sequence that's in OEIS? :-)